# Is it possible to call an instance method from a static method of a class?

Tags: javascript

It's easy to build instance methods that call on the polymorphic static method:

```
class MyClass {
  instanceMethod() {
    this.constructor.staticMethod();
  }
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('first');
  }
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass {
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('second');
  }
}
const i = new OtherClass();
i.instanceMethod();
```

However, I want to do the opposite - define a static method that calls upon the polymorphic instance method - sending `this` as a parameter.

```
class MyClass {
  instanceMethod() {
    console.log('first');
    this.constructor.staticMethod();
  }
  static staticMethod(self) {
     // how to call??
     instancefromstatic(this).instanceMethod.call(self);
  }
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass {
  instanceMethod() {
    console.log('second');
  }
}
OtherClass.staticMethod({});
```

Comment: `self.instanceMethod()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you are after…

When you call `OtherClass.staticMethod()`, `this` will be the `OtherClass`. So if you want to access the instance method, you will find it on the `this.prototype`.

```js
class MyClass {
    instanceMethod() {
      console.log('first');
      this.constructor.staticMethod();
    }
    static staticMethod(self) {
       this.prototype.instanceMethod()
       return this.prototype.testVal
    }
  }
  
class OtherClass extends MyClass {
    instanceMethod() {
        console.log('second');
    }
    get testVal(){
        console.log("getting")
        return "test value"
  }

}

// logs 'second':
console.log(OtherClass.staticMethod({}));
```

Be careful in the `MyClass` `instanceMethod`, because you can create an infinite loop the way you have it setup if you call `MyClass.staticMethod()`

Comment: I realize now my real problem was I was trying to do this with a getter. Any way to define the 'this' context in a getter? (this.prototype.getter evaluates to the return of the function before we can even do a .call)

Comment: Hey @NathanielTucker, again, if I understand …if you have a getter on `OtherClass` like `get testVal(){ return "something"}` you can access `this.prototype.testVal` the same way — it will call the getter and return the value.

Comment: @NathanielTucker, I added it to the example above.

Comment: but I want testVal called with the correct 'this' context. Your example 'this' will be undefined.

Comment: Hmm, I think I might need an example of how you want to call it, @NathanielTucker. So far, not instance has been created so I'm not sure what `this` should be.

Comment: if it were a function I would do `this.prototype.instanceMethod.call(self)` (as from my example). this makes 'self' the 'this' context.

Comment: So if you are passing an instance as `self`, can't you call `self.instanceMethod` inside the `staticMethod`?

Comment: well the idea was to pass in a plain object with the same shape.

Answer (score -1):

`Instance` is merely a `context` of a method call in this case.
You are almost getting there. Passing in `self` to the staticMethod.
And then you can call it via class name.

`MyClass.instanceMethod.call(self)`